# Excel VSTO: Use ResourceDictionary which is in separate assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, vsto, resourcedictionary, assemblyinfo

In my VSTO Application, I need to use the ResourceDictionary which is in separate assembly.

I created a separate ResourceDictionary named `generic.xaml` in the VSTO application under `themes` folder like `/themes/generic.xaml`. In that file, I have referenced the ResourceDictionary from the external assembly using the Pack URIs.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ExternalAssemblyName;component/Themes/resource.xaml"  />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

Also changed AssemblyInfo to the following:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,
ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
```

But still found no luck. Any help would be good.

**P.S.** Please don't suggest putting ResourceDictionary in App.Xaml because I am working on VSTO application so there will be no App.xaml.

Comment: If the file name is generic.xaml then define the pack url as `pack://application:,,,/ExternalAssemblyName;component/Themes/generic.xaml`. Also, does you shared assembly is being loaded into AppDomain?

Comment: Yes, I have defined the pack url as per the file name of the resourcedictionary.No, Can you please tell me how to load the shared assembly into AppDomain?

Answer (score 1):

Using VSTO does not prevent you from using App.xaml :)

1. Create an App.xaml as you normally would and import resource dictionary in Application.Resources
2. In add-in startup initialise WPF application

   ```
   private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       //Ensure the singleton WPF Application is instantiated
       if (System.Windows.Application.Current == null)
       {
           new App();
       }

       //Take control of WPF application shutdown
       System.Windows.Application.Current.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
   }
   ```
3. Make sure to shutdown WPF application when closing add-in

   ```
   private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       if (System.Windows.Application.Current != null)
       {
           System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use your styles in XAML

[Example on Github](https://github.com/didzispetkus/vsto-external-resource-library)

Comment: Checked your GitHub project - and it does work! But inside the VS it reports an error in `MyWindow.xaml`, the error is: "MyLabelStyle could not be resolved". It does not prevent this to work, but it is not a way to work inside VS with errors. How can it be fixed? May be some dictionary reference?